# Android switching switch buttons on iteration

Tags: android, listview, android-arrayadapter, android-switch

In a custom arrayadapter I have a list of string values being either "true" or "false".

```
public class CustomFriendList  extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

private final Activity context;
private List<String> friendName = new ArrayList<String>();
private List<String> backchatable = new ArrayList<String>();


public CustomFriendList(Activity context, List<String> friendName, List<String> backchatable){
    super(context, R.layout.fragment_friend_list_item, friendName);
    this.context = context;
    this.friendName = friendName;
    this.backchatable = backchatable;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();
    View rowView= inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_friend_list_item, null, true);
    TextView friend = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.friendName);
    Switch switchBackChat = (Switch) rowView.findViewById(R.id.on_off_backchatable);

    friend.setText(friendName.get(position));

    for (String ele : backchatable) {
        //System.out.println(ele.toString());
        if(ele.equals("false")){
            switchBackChat.setChecked(false);
        }else if(ele.equals("true")){
            switchBackChat.setChecked(true);
        }
    }

    return rowView;
}


}
```

I am looking to set the state of the switches according to the values "true" or "false".

However the code above switches all the switches in the custom listView and not the respective ones at some position in the listView.

Comment: Could you post your whole getView method please? Also, as @Pavneet_Singh has suggested, you aren't checking the string values correctly (use ele.equals("false") instead as that is the correct way to check a string value in Java).

Comment: the check from == to .equals is correct. However the individual switches are not changed accordingly. They are all changed together.

Answer (score 2):

Use ele.equals("false") and ele.equals("true") in the if statements or just use booleans instead of string values.

And why are you setting the checked status while iterating through the backchatable array? By this only the last string of the array matters and if the last string is "false" the switch will not be checked and if the last string is "true" the switch will be checked.

Comment: This is exactly the problem. But how to go about changing the switches independently then? I've been trying to set the listView items that contain a textView and the switch coherently but because I was unable to update them from a common list so I made two lists.

Comment: Check the edit. Essentially I am trying to put into each listView row the combination of the "friend name" in the textView and set the switch to either "true / false" Unfortunately I have to do this process extracting the data from two lists because from a JSONObject I cannot create a single list that this custom arrayadapter can act upon to render the listView.

Comment: the getView method gets called for every row of your listview. The parameter position tells you which row item should be returned. So when position is 0 the first row of the list should be returned. So you have to check if backchatable.get(position) is equals "true" or "false". You don't need to iterate through the list. Just use the get method like you do when getting the friend name.

Comment: Thank you, that explained a lot!